# How to add tabIndex = '0' in TypeScript div?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6, frontend

I am using Typescript with NextJS, i want to add `tabIndex = '0'` in one of the div. but am getting this error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`... how to achive this?

```
‹div className= 'container' tabIndex = '0'>
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, for future questions please write the code into a code block instead of linking to a screenshot. I've edited this question to do so now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `tabIndex='0'` , you should write it as `tabIndex={0}`. This way Ty[escript will understand.
`<div className="container tabIndex={0}>`

Comment: You're missing a quote in that html I think..

Answer (score 1):

I think typescript is wrong here, since it ends up as a string in html anyway.

But to please the compiler, pass `tabIndex` as a JS value like this:

```
<div className="container tabIndex={0}>
```

Comment: Whoever designed the TypeScript definition files made it so that React tabIndex needs to be a number, similarly with rowSpan of a table cell, etc. –

Comment: Yes, and I disagree with that definiition `nunber | string` would be more ergonomic